# Change BlazeDS protocol from AFM3 to AMF0

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, blazeds

I have installed blazeds-turnkey-4.0.0.14931 installed.  By default Blazeds uses AMF3 protocol. I wan't to switch it to AMF0. How to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why?  I would have expected AMF3 was backward compatible w/ AMF0; but can't find docs stating that

Comment: I'm writting AMF network protocol parser and need to test it with AMF0 :)

Comment: That makes sense.  I'm told most AMF3 serializers know how to speak AMF0; so I'd expect the one from Adobe to do so.  Have you tried sending AMF0 packets to BlazeDS?  What was the error message or issue you ran into?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to http://www.rooftopsolutions.nl/blog/88

AMF3 is built on top of AMF0 as far I understand; AMF3 brings with it support for more complex data like XML and referenced objects/strings if I remember correctly.

I haven't worked with BlazeDS, but in amfPHP the request is parsed differently depending on the object encoding you specify in your service request; to summarize, change the encoding in Flex and BlazeDS should respond accordingly.

Comment: Ok. Now I realized that I need to configure my flex application to do this. Now question sounds like: "How to change AMF encoding in FLEX project in Flash Builder"?